# How to Launch specific activity on press My App icon on recent apps menu

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

I am using Admob SDK on my app, my I load the add `onCreate` and `onResume`, Now when the user press back to exit the app quickly the application display `Interstitial` ad after few seconds, and the user may close it, So far no problems, but when the user press the app icon from the recent apps; it display blank activity of Admob `AdActivity`

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (resumeAdFlag) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    } else {
        resumeAdFlag = true;
    }
}
```

and on add loaded

```
public void onAdLoaded() {
        displayInterstitial();
        super.onAdLoaded();
}
```

and this to display

```
public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
        resumeAdFlag = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it displaying blank activity after a moment or instantly?
Can you try loading the ad in onResume() and after 5 seconds, calling displayInterstitial() as shown below?
or can you try interstitial with a different ad_unit_id when showing after onResume()?

> new CountDownTimer(5000, 5) {
>
> ```
>                   @Override
>             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
>                                     }
>                         @Override
>                         public void onFinish() {
>                 displayInterstitial();
>                         }
>                     }.start();
> ```